# Running PowerPoint in Presentation Mode in Windows 7 from Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, windows-7, scheduled-tasks, powerpoint

I am having a problem with getting a PowerPoint presentation to run in presentation mode in Windows 7.
I set up a scheduled task with a trigger of every day at a certain time and the action as opening PowerPoint with the command line arguments
/s "directory/test.ppsx"
When this is ran, it doesn't take  full screen and play like it did in XP.  It plays in the background of the other windows and the PowerPoint icon in the task bar glows orange/yellow.  If i click on the PowerPoint icon in the taskbar, the presentation displays as normal.
How can i prevent the presentation form needing a user to acknowledge that its gonna play before it will?

Answer (score 0):

Save the file as PPS PowerPoint Show and it will run in presentation mode :)